# which is high performance in spring aop using cglib or jdk proxy without aspectj?

Tags: java, spring, proxy, aop, cglib

we have implemented the spring AOP into our application without using aspectj.
We made the auto proxy as true to make it use CGLIB proxy.

The reason we made it as proxy target class = 'true' to resolve the proxy error. as a side effect the application becomes slow and taking longer time to execute.

Is there a way out of this which will help us to keep performance intact and also to escape the proxy error.

```
<!-- Aspects -->
    <bean id="loggingAspect" class="web.aspect.LogAspectAroundMethod" />
    <!-- PointCut -->
    <bean id="myLogPointCut" class="org.springframework.aop.support.JdkRegexpMethodPointcut">
    <property name="pattern" value=".*" />
    <property name="excludedPatterns">
    <list>
    <value>.*.isDaemon.*</value>
    </list>
    </property>
    </bean>

    <!-- Advisor Around-->
    <bean id="myLogAroundAdvisor" class="org.springframework.aop.support.DefaultBeanFactoryPointcutAdvisor">
      <property name="adviceBeanName" value="loggingAspect" />
      <property name="pointcut" ref="myLogPointCut" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="aprProxy" class="org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.BeanNameAutoProxyCreator">
    <property name="proxyTargetClass" value="true"/>
    <property name="beanNames">
    <value>*Delegate,*Builder*,*Impl*,*Controller,*Handler,*Helper</value>
    </property>
    <property name="interceptorNames">
    <list>
    <value>myLogAroundAdvisor</value>
    </list>
    </property>
    </bean>
```

Advisor code follows:-

Provided only the implementation part:-

```
    import org.aopalliance.intercept.MethodInterceptor;
    import org.aopalliance.intercept.MethodInvocation;

    public class LogAspectAroundMethod implements MethodInterceptor{

        public Object invoke(MethodInvocation methodInvocation) throws Throwable {

               Object result = methodInvocation.proceed();
               return result;
        }

}
```

Comment: auto-proxing has nothing to do with Cglib or JDK Dynamic Proxies. Either you are confusing things or you meant to say 'proxy-target-class' is `true`.

Comment: yes proxy-target-class is true. Just modified the question as well.

Answer (score 0):

CGLIB is supposed to be faster, JDK proxies use reflection internally (see Spring's JdkDynamicAopProxy), CGLIB proxies call target methods directly via generated code

Comment: Yes CGLIB is supposed to be faster, but it wasn't ! Please suggest if anything else should help me to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

What is slow? Start-up performance or performance later when everything is already set up? Maybe there are performance issues with `JdkRegexpMethodPointcut`, I do not know. Maybe it is the high number of created proxies, you seem to match a lot of classes and methods. Furthermore, your advice themselves may be slow. You are not showing them here. What happens if your advice just calls `proceed()` and does nothing else? Do you even need `around()` advice or would `before()` or `after()` suffice? Many open questions. Try to debug differentially, i.e. change one thing at a time. First trivialise the advice as suggested in order to find out about their performance impact. Also consider to use normal AspectJ matching syntax instead of Regex matching, maybe that is slow. Then try matching fewer classes and measure the impact.

Last but not least, even if you do not want to hear it, consider AspectJ which does not need any proxies. Especially with compile-time weaving you can also minimise the impact on start-up time.

Comment: The issue is with performance later not with start-up. Also added the advisor implementation part. We have used the around() advice. The reason for not using the aspectj was the security concerns. Please suggest for the solution.

Comment: I **have** suggested a way to debug this. Have you even tried? First we need facts, the solution can be concluded from them. BTW, security concerns sounds like a pretty general killer argument. Why should AspectJ be any more dangerous or insecure than Spring AOP?

Comment: Yes the facts are listed below:-

Aspect : We have a event log component which is used logging. 

for this aspect we tried to apply an advise.

We did a performance test and as a result determined that with AOP is slower than and without AOP.

Hence looking for a help. Suggest me if we have any other better way to implement.

As you said AspectJ is a killer argument and we do have a security issue of using that Jar. That's a reason we didn't do that.

Comment: I repeat: Read my answer and perform the profiling steps I told you to. If you want to optimise you need to know where the bottleneck is. "AOP is slow" is not good enough. I do want to help you, but we both need more information about **what** is slow. Proxies? Pointcut matching? Weaving? Advice execution? In this situation it is just not good enough to say: "I have a problem, solve it for me with insufficient information." Do yourself a favour and differentially debug/profile this. You do not want to change the tool. So learn how to wield that tool, don't be yet another fool with a tool.

Comment: One more thought: In order to find the bottleneck think about if the system would also be slow with thousands of log statements added manually. In order to assess the overhead you can temporarily use AspectJ instead of Spring AOP to see if it is still slow - not switching to AJ forever, just for finding out if the problem is really proxies or not.

Comment: Hi,

After serious consideration our organization is decided not to use Aspect J.

We have tested our code with Spring AOP after making changes in the point cut matching. Also we have reduced the logs that included earlier.

But still we are expecting to improve the performance.

Having one question.. for exclude pattern.

Though we exclude the spring classes like interceptors whether those  classes are considered to create proxy by CGLIB or not ?

Comment: Sorry, I am out of here. You do not answer my questions. Why should I continue trying to answer yours? You are making it too hard for me helping you. Ask someone else, please.

Comment: Sorry for short description.

Thanks for helping me out and find an explanation below for your questions:-

The First thing, we did work around with Aspect J and tested as well.The result is better than Spring AOP but due to organization point of view we couldn't continue with Aspect J.

Secondly we have reduced the logging statements.

Third we have modified the exclusion patterns.

At last, the Problem is here with patterns as we are suspecting, that's the bottle neck.

Hope it will help everyone to understand where am I at this moment.

Answer (score 0):

One problem I see is the amount of proxies created combined with the use of `JdkRegexpMethodPointcut`.

When determining if an advice needs to be executed there are 2 parts in play. First there is the static part of the pointcut. This is basically the point where the proxy is created and is, in this case, based on the name. You seem to have quite some beans which need the advice applied.

Second there is the dynamic part which is *executed for each method call* on the proxy. In your case that is a JDK based regular expression which is executed to determine if the method name matches. Now the JDK regexp impementation is known to be slower then other implementations.

I would expect the amount of proxies combined with the regexp is slowing your application down.

I would strongly urge you to try and convince your company and allow the use of AspectJ, why would there be a risk in using a framework that is used by millions of developers? There is more risk in using the AOP alliance thing (what you are using now) as that is used by far less people then AspectJ.